# Special $\omega(n)$-sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $k$ be a natural number, $\omega(n)$ the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

The object is to find a number $n$ with $\omega(n+j)=j+1$ for each $j$ with
$0\le j\le k-1$. In other words, a sequence of $k$ numbers, such that the
number of distinct prime factors increases from $1$ to $k$.

The least examples for some $k$ :

```
  k               n

  2               5
  3              64
  4            1867
  5          491851
  6        17681491
```

Questions :

- Does a number $n$ exists for each $k$ ?
- Is there a good estimate for the magnitude of the least example ?
- Can anyone extend the table ?

Comment: If there is an example for $k=7$ it must be $>10^{10}$.

Comment: This is OEIS https://oeis.org/A086560